# Django url regex hit end of url: *./something

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I am geting 404 on different urls that end with the same string and instead of creating multiple redirects I would like to catch them all on the last string. It always appears at the same position, pattern goes like so:

```
/some-of-my-urls/the-same-string
```

No trailing slash there. I tried something like this:

```
url(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/the-same-string', redirect_func),
url(r'^./the-same-string', redirect_func),
```

But that doesn't work. Probably obvious for somebody with more regex knowledge, I am not very advanced. Anybody ideas?

Comment: Try `r'^[^/]+/the-same-string'`, add named capturing group if necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks Wiktor but it's not catching the requests.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now it does. I had it too down low in the file. The first comment work well. Thanks. If you want the correct answer, repost and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a negated character class `[^/]` to match any char but `/` and quantify it with a `+` quantifier that matches 1 or more repetitions:

```
r'^[^/]+/the-same-string'
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/87FyTz/1).